# RichTextArea - getText().length() for no-text mode returns different values

Tags: gwt, richtextarea

After cut event occurs, I tried to get the RichTextArea inner text length with code like a

```
int l=getRichTextArea().getText().length();
```

... but

- in FF it returns 0
- in Chrome it returns 1

I couldn't have opportunity to test more internet browsers... So my question is...

Why does it happening? And is there a way to make it return correct value as 0 if richtextarea contains no text?

P.S. GWT 2.3

Thanks

Comment: What is the character in FF? Can you print it? If it's some blank string (like space char) you might use `getRichTextArea().getText().trim().length()`.

Comment: @yair I mean the RTA becomes empty(contains no text) right after I select and cut text manually so right after that if I get text length it returns different values in different internet browsers. I tried in FF so it works fine and returns length as 0 just because no-text length is really zero but Chrome in the same case returns 1 :( "What is the character in FF?" I think its text after all-cut becomes "" or null I am not sure anyway I'll try your suggestion

Comment: @yair I guess you are right about the blank string I tried the trim() method and it returns 0 in Chrome too :) Could you please post your answer me to accept it?

Comment: OK good to hear. FF's behavior is still odd, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's some blank string (like space char) you can use

```
getRichTextArea().getText().trim().length()
```

Comment: Thank you :) That really worked; but why Chrome gives length as 1 when text area is empty then? What do you think?

Comment: @user592704 unfortunately I currently don't have an IDE available, I'll try to check it later. It's one of the things you have to see for yourself in order to debug :).